# Manipulation on files with python

Tags: python

I would like to try Python and I am coming from Perl. My first example is a program that:

1. Read the files passed to the program
2. Search for a word starting with a vowel that is minimum 4 chars long
3. Exchange this word with its direct follower
4. Inverse all the lines in the file (the last line become the first one)
5. Put everything in uppercase
6. Display it on stdout

With Perl I can write this:

```
print reverse map uc s/\b(\w+[aeiouy]\w{3,})\s+(\w+)\b/$2 $1/gr, <>;
```

In Python I wrote this:

```
import fileinput
import re
alist = []
for line in fileinput.input():
    alist.append(re.sub(r"\b(\w+[aeiouy]\w{3,})\s+(\w+)\b", r"\2 \1", line.upper()))
print "".join(alist[::-1])
```

It it the right way to write it? Why the regex doesn't work here?

---

Here an example of input file:

```
Suscipit elementum. Nulla accumsan at ex sed viverra.
molestie. In volutpat aliquam massa, vitae arcu ultricies blandit tempus. Donec nisi semper non
commodo nec purus fringilla fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum feugiat a lectus imperdiet
Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora per torquent conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Cras

Phasellus ac condimentum mauris. Sed aliquet leo sagittis nec varius.
```

And the expected output:

```
AC PHASELLUS MAURIS CONDIMENTUM. SED LEO ALIQUET NEC SAGITTIS VARIUS.

CLASS APTENT SOCIOSQU TACITI AD PER LITORA CONUBIA TORQUENT NOSTRA, PER HIMENAEOS INCEPTOS. CRAS
NEC COMMODO FRINGILLA PURUS FRINGILLA. POTENTI SUSPENDISSE. FEUGIAT VESTIBULUM A IMPERDIET LECTUS
MOLESTIE. IN ALIQUAM VOLUTPAT MASSA, ARCU VITAE BLANDIT ULTRICIES TEMPUS. NISI DONEC NON SEMPER
ELEMENTUM SUSCIPIT. ACCUMSAN NULLA AT EX SED VIVERRA.
```

Comment: What is the output of alist, can you give some line that you want to match as an example?

Comment: Consider using Pythex to test your regex with your input: http://pythex.org

Comment: If your regex is working (via testing), then consider breaking down your Python code into smaller pieces to test how it is working.

Comment: @AlexReynolds I used regex101 and the regex seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alist.append(re.sub(r"\b(\w+[aeiouy]\w{3,})\s+(\w+)\b", r"\2 \1", line.upper(),flags=re.I))
```

You have to add the `igonorecase` flag.As you make your line `upper` or `capitals` and in your regex you do not account for that.`[aeiouy]` will match only lower case `vowels` not uppercase.

Also instead of `print` use `sys.stdout.write` as `print` will add an additional `newline`.So your file will have `an empty line` after each line .

Or use

`print something.rstrip()`

Comment: Or just `print something,` which will suppress any additional EOL

Comment: @JonClements dats cool............didnt know about it....have you tested it?how does dat remove the newline which `print` adds.Tested it..it works fine.Thanx.dat was new for me

Comment: well... it's just part of Python 2.x syntax... a tailing comma on a `print` statement prevents a newline being output... (admittedly - not the most natural syntax in the world, but oh well)